# grunt-contrib-watch livereload 35729 livereload.js fails to load

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

I am running grunt-contrib-watch 0.6.1 and have included livereload blocks in my gruntfile.js.  I also included livereload.js call in my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myste.com:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

When I run the server using my dev env everything seems to start correctly.

```
grunt dev
Running "env:dev" (env) task

Running "concurrent:dev" (concurrent) task

Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`

Application Started on port 3000
```

When I make a change I can see the server reload in my ssh console, but livereload.js fails to load:

When I go to the port location where it should be http://myste.com:35729/livereload.js I get the standard "webpage not available" response. There also seems to be no server running on http://myste.com:35729/ at all.

I also include my gruntfile.js here for completeness

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    var watchFiles = {
        serverViews: ['app/views/**/*.*'],
        serverJS: ['gruntfile.js', 'server.js', 'config/**/*.js', 'app/**/*.js'],
        clientViews: ['public/views/**/*.html'],
        clientJS: ['public/js/**/*.js'],
        clientSASS: 'public/styles/sass/**/*.{scss,sass}',
        clientCSS: ['public/styles/css/**/*.css']
    };

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        env: {
            dev: {
                NODE_ENV: 'development'
            },
            prod: {
                NODE_ENV: 'production'
            }
        },
        watch: {
            serverViews: {
                files: watchFiles.serverViews,
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            serverJS: {
                files: watchFiles.serverJS,
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            clientViews: {
                files: watchFiles.clientViews,
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                }
            },
            clientJS: {
                files: watchFiles.clientJS,
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            clientSASS: {
                files: watchFiles.clientSASS,
                tasks: ['sass:dev'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            clientCSS: {
                files: watchFiles.clientCSS,
                tasks: ['csslint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
        },

        nodemon: {
            dev: {
                script: 'server.js'
            }
        },

        nodeunit: {
            dev: {
                all: ['app/test/**/*_test.js'],
                options: {
                    reporter: 'tap',
                    reporterOutput: 'tests.tap',
                    reporterOptions: {
                        output: 'outputdir'
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        jshint: {
            dev: {
                all: {
                    src: watchFiles.clientJS.concat(watchFiles.serverJS),
                    options: {
                        jshintrc: true
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        uglify: {
            prod: {
                my_target: {
                    files: {
                        'public/js/all.min.js': ['public/js/library/jquery.js', 'public/js/library/modernizr.js', 'public/js/library/selectivizr.js', 'public/js/library/delfin.js']
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        sass: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    style: 'expanded'
                },
                files: {
                    'public/styles/css/style.css': 'public/styles/scss/style.scss' // 'destination': 'source'
                }
            }
        },

        cssmin: {
            prod: {
                files: {
                    'public/styles/css/style.min.css': 'public/styles/css/style.css'
                }
            }
        },

        csslint: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    csslintrc: '.csslintrc',
                },
                all: {
                    src: watchFiles.clientCSS
                }
            }
        },

        concurrent: {
            dev: {
                target: {
                    tasks: ['nodemon', 'watch'],
                    options: {
                        logConcurrentOutput: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-csslint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-nodeunit');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express-server');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-env');

    grunt.registerTask('dev', ['env:dev', 'concurrent', 'nodemon', 'watch', 'jshint', 'nodeunit', 'sass']);
    grunt.registerTask('prod', ['env:prod', 'cssmin', 'uglify', 'nodemon']);
};
```

Comment: You're running `concurent task` that includes `watch` and `nodemon` tasks and then running this tasks again. It may cause you problem. Check what's happen if your remove them from `grunt dev` declaration

Comment: @GlenSwift thanks for the suggestion.  I tried removing them from the dev declaration, but then the server doesn't start.  I also tried removing concurrent from dev, the server loaded but the livereload access is still missing.

Comment: Hm, Here is my instance of concurrent task:

    concurrent: {
        tasks: ['nodemon', 'watch'],
        options: {
            logConcurrentOutput: true
        }
    }

I run it with grunt and do not run watch and nodemon seperately. I am not sure this will be helpful but can you try? It works perfectly for me.

Comment: @GlenSwift Yes! you are right.  Your version worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to run `nodemon` and `watch` tasks twice. First, when you run `concurrent` task and second when you call themselves.

Change your `concurrent` task config to

```
concurrent: {
    tasks: ['nodemon', 'watch'],
    options: {
        logConcurrentOutput: true
    }
},
```

And remove extra tasks from `grunt dev` declaration:

```
grunt.registerTask('dev', ['env:dev', 'concurrent', 'jshint', 'nodeunit', 'sass']);
```